# distributed monitoring with process control

Tags: linux, monitoring, remote-access

I am searching a tool for monitoring my web apps, which are deployed accross several machines in the same VPN. However, besides the monitoring service, I would like to control my services (start|stop|restart) from a central place, preferentially web ui. I found [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) , and its great. But, the distributed version ([M/Monit](http://mmonit.com/)) is not free. there is some open source tool with these capabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[M/Monit](http://www.mmonit.com) is inexpensive and the source code is available. [It's only €229 for unlimited hosts](http://mmonit.com/shop/). If you have consistent access to the servers (via VPN or otherwise), it makes sense because it does exactly what you're asking for. Try the evaluation and see how it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

For distributed process control I can recommend [MCollective](http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective/introduction/), which is a great open-source tool for running commands on any number of systems based on various real-time metadata.

> The Marionette Collective AKA MCollective is a framework to build
>   server orchestration or parallel job execution systems.
>
> Primarily we’ll use it as a means of programmatic execution of Systems
>   Administration actions on clusters of servers. In this regard we
>   operate in the same space as tools like Func, Fabric or Capistrano.
>
> We’ve attempted to think out of the box a bit designing this system by
>   not relying on central inventories and tools like SSH, we’re not
>   simply a fancy SSH “for loop.” MCollective use modern tools like
>   Publish Subscribe Middleware and modern philosophies like real time
>   discovery of network resources using meta data and not hostnames.
>   Delivering a very scalable and very fast parallel execution
>   environment.

I'm not aware of a monitoring system that has this functionality integrated. Maybe you could integrate it with Nagios' exception handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/), and you can write exception handlers in Nagios to deal with down processes.

Comment: I'm able to start,stop or restart a service via web UI?

Comment: Ah, right, the control thing.  I think that would be hard inside Nagios, as it reacts to state changes of the monitored service.  It can be done, since you can write scripts, but not worth the effort given that it's possible to run cluster/parallel ssh commands.  (In our setup, we'd use chef-server tools, e.g., "knife ssh "role:webserver" 'sudo service nginx restart' or something like that)